# Error de sintaxis en Procedimiento Almacenado

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente codigo para crear un procedimiento almacenado:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateProductos(
    _Id int,
    _Producto varchar(60),
    _CategoriaId int,
    _Descripcion varchar(400),
    _UsuarioModificador varchar(60), 
    _Estado int
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE _categoriaDesc VARCHAR(60);
    SELECT _categoriaDesc=(SELECT Top 1 Descripcion from categoria where Id=_CategoriaId);

    Update productos set (Producto=_Producto,CategoriaId=_CategoriaId,Descripcion=_Descripcion,FchMod=Now(),
                          UserMod=_UsuarioModificador,Estado=_Estado)
                          where Id=_Id;

    insert into bitacora(Usuario,Motivo,Fecha,Tabla) 
    values
        (_UsuarioCreador,CONCAT('se actualizo la tabla productos= Producto: ',_Producto,' Descripcion: ',_Descripcion,' CategoriaID: ',_categoriaDesc),Now(),'productos');

END
```

y me muestra el siguiente error:

```
#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 11.
```

Comment: Declaras la variable `_categoriaDesc` pero luego tratas de setear `categoriaDesc`

Comment: y de que manera le asigno un valor retornado por una consulta a esa variable? soy nuevo en mysql

Comment: si es por lo del guion, no es eso ya probe y nada, lo que pasa es que he intentado de todo, cambiar nombre a la variable

Comment: podrías ponerlo en código y que no sea una imagen ?

Comment: Intenta con `SELECT...INTO`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html

Comment: ya la coloque en codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edite tu código, prueba así:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateProductos(
                    _Id int,
                    _Producto varchar(60),
                    _CategoriaId int,
                    _Descripcion varchar(400),
                    _UsuarioModificador varchar(60), 
                    _Estado int
                )
                BEGIN

                    DECLARE _categoriaDesc VARCHAR(60);

                    SET _categoriaDesc = (SELECT Descripcion from categoria where Id=_CategoriaId LIMIT 1);

                    Update productos set  Producto = _Producto,
                                          CategoriaId = _CategoriaId, 
                                          Descripcion = _Descripcion, 
                                          FchMod = Now(),
                                          UserMod = _UsuarioModificador,
                                          Estado = _Estado
                    where Id=_Id;

                    insert into bitacora(Usuario,Motivo,Fecha,Tabla) 
                    values
                        (_UsuarioCreador,CONCAT('se actualizo la tabla productos= Producto: ',_Producto,' Descripcion: ',_Descripcion,' CategoriaID: ',_categoriaDesc),Now(),'productos');

                END
```

Comment: y que fue lo que corregiste o donde estaba el fallo?

Comment: 1) no estaba setiando su variable `_categoriaDesc`
2) estaba ulitilizando `TOP 1` en lugar de `LIMIT 1` que es utilizado por el motor de mysql.